# Sort pandas cells (strings) according to matching string in column name

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, sorting

Given the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'doc' : ['2739','2697','3135','896'],
               'tool' : ["system: 15", "architectur: 5" ,"tool: 10", "tool: 11"],
               'system' : ["tool: 1", "tool: 3" , "system: 5", "system: 14"],
               'architectur' : ["architectur: 4", "system: 28", "architectur: 3", "architectur: 10"]})

df = df.set_index('doc')


print(df)
               tool      system      architectur
doc                                              
2739      system: 15     tool: 1   architectur: 4
2697  architectur: 5     tool: 3       system: 28
3135        tool: 10   system: 5   architectur: 3
896         tool: 11  system: 14  architectur: 10
```

I am trying to reorder the strings according to matching strings from the column name.

The ultimate goal is then the aquire this:

```
          tool      system      architectur
doc                                        
2739   tool: 1  system: 15   architectur: 4
2697   tool: 3  system: 28   architectur: 5
3135  tool: 10   system: 5   architectur: 3
896   tool: 11  system: 14  architectur: 10
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can re-construct your dataframe

```
yourdf=pd.DataFrame([dict(map(tuple,[y.split(':') for y in x ])) for x in (df.values.tolist())],index=df.index)
yourdf
Out[159]: 
     architectur system tool
doc                         
2739           4     15    1
2697           5     28    3
3135           3      5   10
896           10     14   11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In addition to the data frame from above I now have one with empty strings "" as well as NaN. How can I ignore these values when reordering?

Comment: @Peter fill the empty with their columns name with :